# Client certification coming back as anonymous in iis/c#

Tags: c#, authentication, wcf, iis, certificate

I have a small c# application that makes a call to another service. That call requires a certification that expired the other week. I created a new certificate and this new certificate is working everywhere (locally, dev, and sit) except for my UAT environment. Nothing changed except for the certification.

I can't figure out why I keep getting this error: "The HTTP Request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'."

Clearly the cert in UAT isn't working but it should. It works everywhere else. I've checked the folder permissions and also that the service we are making a call to is up to date and has our cert whitelisted.

I don't know much about IIS but i have restarted it multiple times and even tried to install the cert on our server. nothing works and I don't know where to go anymore. I've compared a nonworking and working environment and nothing stands out.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm really struggling with this.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Does the UAT server trust the issuer of the certificate, and is it joined to the same domain as the client (or the two domains have a trust relationship)?

Comment: Yes and yes they are joined to the same domain

Comment: Have you set up client certificate mapping https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication/

Comment: Yes, Client Certificate Mapping has also been set up

Comment: You probably got the error message from WCF components, so enable WCF tracing to learn more, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing

Comment: The problem might be with the certificate of the server you are accessing, make sure you have imported the private key. If not, try importing the private key into LocalMachine's "Trusted Root" store. In addition, you need to check whether the relevant firewall rules are set to cause the problem.

Comment: I tried to enable wcf tracing but i got nothing. im also just not that familiar with it...

I have the private key so that isn't the issue either. :(

Comment: You need to ensure that the certificate's chain of trust is complete in the UAT environment. Also, enable verbose logging in your application to capture any information related to certificate issues. For us, it is impossible to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.